# Floating point addition algorithm

Tags: rust, floating-point

I'm attempting to write an addition algorithm of two floating point numbers in Rust. I have nearly got it to work, but there are a few cases when the final mantissa is one off from what it should be. (I'm not yet dealing with subnormal numbers). My algorithm is:

```rs
fn add_f32(a: f32, b: f32) -> f32 {
    let a_bits = a.to_bits();
    let b_bits = b.to_bits();
    let a_exp = (a_bits << 1) >> (23 + 1);
    let b_exp = (b_bits << 1) >> (23 + 1);
    
    let mut a_mant = a_bits & 0x007fffff;
    let mut b_mant = b_bits & 0x007fffff;

    let mut a_exp = (a_exp as i32).wrapping_sub(127);
    let mut b_exp = (b_exp as i32).wrapping_sub(127);

    if b_exp > a_exp {
        // If b has a larger exponent than a, swap a and b so that a has the larger exponent
        core::mem::swap(&mut a_mant, &mut b_mant);
        core::mem::swap(&mut a_exp, &mut b_exp);
    }

    let exp_diff = (a_exp - b_exp) as u32;

    // Add the implicit leading 1 bit to the mantissas
    a_mant |= 1 << 23;
    b_mant |= 1 << 23;

    // Append an extra bit to the mantissas to ensure correct rounding
    a_mant <<= 1;
    b_mant <<= 1;

    // If the shift causes an overflow, the b_mant is too small so is set to 0
    b_mant = b_mant.checked_shr(exp_diff).unwrap_or(0);

    let mut mant = a_mant + b_mant;
    let overflow = (mant >> 25) != 0;
    if !overflow {
        // Check to see if we round up
        if mant & 1 == 1 {
            mant += 1;
        }
    }
    
    // check for overflow caused by rounding up
    let overflow = overflow || (mant >> 25) != 0;
    mant >>= 1;

    if overflow {
        if mant & 1 == 1 {
            mant += 1;
        }
        // Check to see if we round up
        mant >>= 1;
        a_exp += 1;
    }

    // Remove implicit leading one
    mant <<= 9;
    mant >>= 9;
    
    f32::from_bits(mant | ((a_exp.wrapping_add(127) as u32) << 23))
}
```

For example, the test

```rs
#[test]
fn test_add_small() {
    let a = f32::MIN_POSITIVE;
    let b = f32::from_bits(f32::MIN_POSITIVE.to_bits() + 1);
    let c = add_f32(a, b);
    let d = a + b;
    assert_eq!(c, d);
}
```

fails, with the actual answer being `00000001000000000000000000000000` (binary representation) and my answer being `00000001000000000000000000000001`.

Is anyone able to help me with what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think this code may be intended to use “round to nearest, ties to even”. In that case, insufficient bits are kept to determine the rounding, and the test `if mant & 1 == 1` is wrong. Suppose we are looking at some bits where we want to round, say x|yz, where x is the last bit position that will be kept, y is the next bit, and z is a summary of all the following bits. (If all following bits are 0, z will be zero. Otherwise, z will be 1.) If y and z are 1, we need to round up. If y is zero, we need to round down. If y is 1 and z is 0, we have a tie. Then, if x is 0, we round down. Else up.

Comment: In this, z is called a “sticky” bit. When you shifted the significand of b (“significand” is the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point number; “mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion for of a logarithm), you should not just let all of its bits be shifted out. If its high bit is shifted just beyond the rounding position (it will become y), then you also need to know whether any of the shifted-out bits were 1 (to make z). And you need to adjust your other checking of the rounding conditions to use these extra bits.

Comment: In the particular case you cite, the exponents are equal, so there is no shifting of b’s significand for that. Then, when you add them, you will have 010 in the low bits of the significand. (Currently, you have only 01, which is not enough for correct rounding decisions; you need to shift the significands left one more position and keep the necessary information.) With 01, your current code is looking at the 1 and deciding to round up. But we do not round up for ties where the previous digit is zero; we keep it even.

Comment: So, that code ought to be “If the part being removed by rounding is exactly ½, look at the previous bit. If it is 0, leave it. If it is 1, add 1 there.” But, again, we need two bits after that rounding position: For 00, round down. For 01, round down. For 10, use the ties-to-even by looking at the previous bit. For 11, round up.